# How to properly access child key value pairs in a php object?

Tags: php

If I have an object that looks something like this:

```
business = {
    location: {
        address: '123 fake ave',
        lat: '25',
        lng: '25'
    },
    name: 'fake company',
    number: '123-123-123',
    website: 'website.com'
}
```

How would I properly access the lat and lng key value pairs inside the object?

I got it to work by doing:

```
$lat = $business->location['lat'];
```

How come I can't do:

```
$lat = $business->location->lat;
```

Is the method that I used the 'correct' method or is there a better way.

Thank you.

Comment: because `location` is an array, not an object - you use array keys like this `$array['key']` - you get object properties like this `$obj->prop`

Comment: Hey @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs, how is location an array? I thought to declare arrays, you would need to use square brackets.

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs Location is an object, not an array...

Comment: well for one, you're using a JSON object - not a PHP array - why not try var dumping $business - obviously it's an array or else `->lat` would work

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs ahh that makes a lot of sense. I am using a makeshift function to log stuff into console so that is probably messing with the structure. Thanks for clearing this up!

Comment: "I thought to declare arrays, you would need to use square brackets" - There's no way to answer language syntax questions with pseudo-code. If `$business->location['lat']` location works and `$business->location->lat` doesn't it's exactly because of what ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs said but there's no way to deduce it from the data dump in the question.